# Xamarin IOS Writing to Production iCloud failing

Tags: c#, ios, xamarin, icloud

So I recently installed my application on the App Store and found the the restore from iCloud function does not work in my app. However, what I found by looking the on the App Center on my windows machine, it is not the restore at all, each of my records I am writing out to the iCloud is rejected so there is nothing to restore. The error just says error writing record and then gives the record information of the record trying to be written which looks fine to me. So what I am wondering, is there something special I need to do when my app is set to Production in order to write out a record to iCloud? I am using the following code.

```
ThisApp.PrivateDatabase.SaveRecord(newRecord, (record, err) =>
{

     //Analytics.TrackEvent("In Save Record");


     // Was there an error?                                      
        if (err != null)
        {
            Analytics.TrackEvent("Error = " + err);
            Crashes.GenerateTestCrash();
        }
 });
```

Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Just to maybe help someone else that is having trouble saving to and getting data from iCloud, I will let you know the solution to my problem. Nessled down in a posting on one of the sites, was a mention about the iCloud dashboard Production version. It eluded to needing your record type definition in Production. The problem I had was on each of my backups I created a new record type with a unique name. Based on needing to set security on a specific record type, I had to create a generic record type name in prod and accumulate all my backups in there based on 2 new keys I added to the output. This worked and now I am reading from and writing to iCloud from my code coming from the App Store.